# Import Excel to Database

Tags: c#, database, excel, winforms

I'm trying to import an excel document into a database.

I have successfully done this, however, the problem that occurs is that, the data I'm trying to insert, gets inserted four times instead of once.

Here is my code:

```
private void upload_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((tick.Visible != true)|(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cat_combobox.Text))|(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subcat_combobox.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Select an excel file.", "Error: Missing Excel Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            IExcelDataReader excelreader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs); //'97-03 USE: CreateBinaryReader, 07+ USE: CreateOpenXmlReader
            //CREATE COLUMN NAMES FROM FIRST ROW
            excelreader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
            DataSet ds = excelreader.AsDataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            while (excelreader.Read())
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if ((!(row["Item"].Equals(DBNull.Value))) | (!(row["Quantity"].Equals(DBNull.Value))) | (!(row["Date"].Equals(DBNull.Value))))
                        importtodb(Convert.ToInt32(this.cat_combobox.SelectedValue), this.subcat_combobox.Text.ToString(), row["Item"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(row["Quantity"]), row["Date"].ToString());
                }
            }
            excelreader.Close();
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

}

private void importtodb(int catid, string subcat, string item, int quantity, string date)
{
    using (var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO inventory_table (categoryid, Subcategory, Item, Quantity, Date) VALUES(@catid, @subcat, @item, @quantity, @date)", sqlconnection))
    {
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", catid);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subcat", subcat);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantity );
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using ExcelDataReader.

How would I fix the issue of duplicate data being inserted into the database from the code?

Comment: Once you have the data in the DataSet, you shouldn't be using the ExcelDataReader anymore - the data are already loaded into the DataSet. Also, there is no point in using `new DataTable()` as you overwrite that value on the next line.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I agree with John Saunders, try removing the while before the foreach loop.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I've removed the while statement and its working as it should. Thank you!

Comment: That's great. This would be a good time for you to figure out how you could have discovered that for yourself. That will help you next time around. I suspect you would have found the problem if you had single-stepped through your code. Try it with the old code and see if you can't _see_ the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the data in the DataSet, you shouldn't be using the ExcelDataReader anymore - the data are already loaded into the DataSet.

Also, there is no point in using new DataTable() as you overwrite that value on the next line.